# Bound Textbox/Labels not updating when OnPropertyChanged fired

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a simple application which uses a BindingList<(Person)>, people, to store information about employees (Windows Forms). Person has several properties such as Name, DateOfBirth, etc and implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

The BindingList<(Person)>, people, is bound to a binding source. A DataGridView control is bound to this source, and as expected property changes are updated on the DataGridView. For example, when I change the age of a person the DataGridView updates immediately.

My problem occurs when I use the same binding source other controls. I have the text property of a text box bound to Person.Name, using the same binding source as the DataGridView. Changes to the Person.Name property update on the DataGridView, but not to the text box.

How can I make the text box update, like the DataGridView, when a property changes?

Chris

Comment: Does your binding to the TextBox include the DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged parameter?

Comment: @TreDub: make that an answer, it's prob. right.

Comment: Yes, it's set to DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged. It doesn't update the value though. Is there anything else I need to enable to allow OnPropertyChanged to work?

Comment: Okay, I've figured out that the textbox doesn't update when the property is changed from a thread other than the GUI thread (although the DataGridView does), is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Just quickly, this is untested, it probably needs to be handled by a Dispatcher.  Try using the following in place of your TextBox

```
public class DispatchedTextBox : TextBox
    {
        DispatchEvent _propertyChanged = new DispatchEvent();

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this._propertyChanged.Fire(this, e);
        }

        protected override event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
        {
            add { this._propertyChanged.Add(value); }
            remove { this._propertyChanged.Remove(value); }
        }
    }
```